# Switching asp.net cookie and cookieless mode at runtime based on client

Tags: asp.net, session-state, session-cookies

I Would like to use cookies based session tracking for web browsers and cookieless session tracking for mobile clients (ex. UIWebView).

Note: i cannot use cookieless mode for web client because of SEO stuffs, i cannot use cookies on mobile devices because of lack of support for cookies in them.

Wondering is there any possibility?

thanks in advance..

Comment: I think that you have to solve more bugs than the good you try to get. Anyway normally the site for mobile and normal clients are different, you can setup two different applications with different web.config.

Comment: yes iOS supports but Win8 doesn't

Comment: Use the user-agent to identify the browser and switch to cookies or cookieless